# ShowDialog using MVP

Tags: java, android, mvp

I have a view called ILoginView and on it I have a `showDialog(String message)` and on my LoginPresenter I have the call to api so if it fails I do `view.showDialog(context.getString(R.string.response_server_error));` so my question is, when I implement the interface on my mainActivity and I have to override this method, there is the correct way to place the :

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Click on Image for tag");
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong but if I understand your question correctly, you are asking about where to place the code to show `AlertDialog` related code in the `MVP` pattern. Usually the generic idea is that `Presenter` shouldn't have any `Android` specific code. It should be just a `POJO` class. It makes your business logic inside the Presenter class easier to test using just `JUnit` testing. So something like below should work:

Inside Presenter:

```
void onServerCallErrorReturned() {
    view.showErrorDialog();
}
```

Inside Activity:

```
void showErrorDialog() {
    // Here your AlertDialog code can go.
    showDialog(getString(R.string.response_server_error));
}

void showDialog(String message) {
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm asking. So it’s like I’ve did it already, right? On my presenter I have view.showDialog() and then on my Activity I create the Alert.Builder stuff.

Comment: Right. You are on the right track. Its just that when you mentioned calling something like `view.showDialog(context.getString(R.string.response_server_error));` in your Presenter, it seems that you are having reference to the `Context` in your presenter, which ideally shouldn't be there imo.

Comment: And where should I put the context? or at least the context.getString()...?

Comment: Activity or the view

Comment: But then how do I get the String for R.string without the context?

Comment: If you write `showDialog(getString(R.string.response_server_error));` in a method in activity, it will already assume the Activity context. However inside activity you can also do `this.showDialog(getString(R.string.response_server_error));` or `getContext().showDialog(getString(R.string.response_server_error));`. Any of these should work.

Comment: So I have to set the text on Activity nor in the presenter?

Comment: @StuartDTO Right. Any UI related code usually goes in your Activity / Fragment / View. So `setText` would be in Activity